# Swingworker Timeout

Tags: java, swing, timeout, swingworker

I am using a SwingWorker to read data over a TCP connection and display when it comes back.

```
new SwingWorker<EnvInfoProto, Void>() {
  @Override
  public EnvInfoProto doInBackground() {
    try {   
      xxx.writeTo(socket.getOutputStream());
      return ProtoMsg.parseFrom(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch(IOException ignore) { }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void done() {
    try {
      UpdateGui(get());
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
  }
}.execute();
```

The problem arises when the socket is dead, e.g. after writeTo it waits eternally for input on the socket. What is the easiest way to timeout after a while? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356670/timeout-a-task-with-javas-swingworker) also the best solution in this case? Would I still use a swingworker in that solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the solution you linked to is a reasonable and easy solution ("best" is so subjective :) You could leverage [SwingWorker#get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), that is part of the Future interface:

```
SwingWorker<EnvInfoProto, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<EnvInfoProto, Void>() {
    ...
};
worker.execute();
worker.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
//will block 15 seconds at most, then throw TimeoutException
```

Of course you could come up with different ways to reach your goal, but I'd bet there is more code involved than in this solution, so I'd give it a try.