# Progress monitor of stream

Tags: java, stream, progress

I've created a stream from client to server. How to create `ProgressMonitorInputStream` or something else in this kind, for this piece of code?

```
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch = fileStream.read();
            exitStream.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
        while(ch != -1);
        fileStream.close();
```

Updated code - the window appear, but it's empty. Only a frame. How to fix it?

```
         String fileName = "aaa.jpg";
         File fileToBeSend = new File(fileName);

         InputStream input = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
         null, 
         "Reading: " + fileName, 
         new FileInputStream(fileToBeSend));

         int ch;
         do 
         {
             ch = input.read();
            exitStream.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch)); 
         } while(ch != -1);

         input.close();
```

Comment: You've done it. What's the question?

Comment: And that means, that main question is not answered. And main question is: "How to create ProgressMonitorInputStream or something else in this kind, for this piece of code? ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply mean, how to use nested streams, something like this?

```
    ProgressMonitorInputStream input = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
         null, 
         "Reading: " + file, 
         new FileInputStream(file));

    ProgressMonitor monitor = input.getProgressMonitor();
    // do some configuration for monitor here

    int ch;
    do {
        ch = input.read();
        // note: writing also the last -1 value
        exitStream.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch)); 
    } while(ch != -1);

    input.close();
```

Comment: @Noran I have no idea what `exitStream` is, I just copy-pasted and modified the code in your question...

Comment: The "Progress" window appears, but its empty. There is no progress bar inside of it.PS: Yea sorry. I am tired and `exitStream` is a translated name from my lenguage.

Comment: The same happens when I use the code from @Vishal K . Window appear but its empty. It's just a frame.

Comment: @Noran Note sure what the problem could be, but I'd add some other GUI code just to see that works (like google java gui hello world). Then I would try configuring the progress monitor, edited the code in my answer to have template for that.

Comment: Check out my update, maybe there is some small thing that I can't see. After tons of hours with code its quite possible.

Answer (score 1):

For [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) to work , You need to read very big file. It is specified in its document that:

> This creates a progress monitor to monitor the progress of reading the
>   input stream. **If it's taking a while, a ProgressDialog will be popped
>   up to inform the user.** If the user hits the Cancel button an
>   InterruptedIOException will be thrown on the next read. All the right
>   cleanup is done when the stream is closed.

Here is the example. Make sure that you input a file(`bigFile.txt`) contains lot of stuffs to read.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream;

public class ProgressMonitorInputStreamDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  String file = "bigFile.txt";
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  JLabel filenameLabel = new JLabel(file, JLabel.RIGHT);
  filenameLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
  Object message[] = { "Reading:", filenameLabel };
  ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null, message, fis);
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(pmis);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  br.close();
  }
}
```

**Note:** *If you want to see `ProgressBar` , no matter how small file you are reading , You can use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) . Have a look at* **[this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710912/1981279)**.

Comment: I can find this kind of tutorial by myself. I am asking for solution for this particular code that I've quoted in main post. Because for this moment it is a problem for me to do it by myself.

Comment: Look at the Post that I have written in the **Note** section.. And yes of course you can find tutorials..But I expect that after going through those tutorials and few Tips you would easily solve your problem...

Comment: Yes I understand that Note section. But i don't really need it for small files. So I took file big enough for this, and after that window appears. But this window is empty. I've tried 2 codes, yours with additional streams, and the one from @hyde.

Comment: Then post your updated code ..

Comment: I've posted the one from @hyde - because for now it's simpler and more intuitive for me.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code as it is working fine at my end ..Except for `exitStream` I am using `SOP`. What is the size of file that you are reading?

Comment: File got about 400MB. Second file had 2GB. exitStream is:        `socket = new Socket(ip, port);                              exitStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`