# Java: some sort of loadingtext whilst reading/writing to file (DL from URL)

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, inputstream, jtextpane

I'm downloading a file from an URL and while this is going on I'd want to have some sort of loadingtext. No percentage is needed, just some indication that it's working with something.

```
    String zipTo = "src/client.zip";

    URL website = new URL(link);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int len;
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipTo);
    InputStream in = website.openStream();
    in.read();

        while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    ZipHandler zh = new ZipHandler();
    zh.unZipFile(zipTo);
```

When the while-loop is going I'd like some loadingtext. I have a static JTextPane in my JFrame which acts as the status text. Something like "Loading . . . " (which has a sleeper between the dots).

Any tips?

Edit:
I'm afraid I have very little experience with threads, and after reading about it I have noe clue how to implement it so it fits with my entire code.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)?

Comment: Not exactly. I'd more just like a progresstext. I updated the title and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You block `EDT`, because of your peogressText doesn't updating. You need to use `SwingWorker` for updating your status label.

Read about [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for background processes and updating UI from that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710912/2894369) is a good example with `SwingWorker` and updating UI.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to get sort of what I wanted using some simple SwingWorker. I've always thought Threads were to be used, but SwingWorker seems more sensible. Thanks again!