# HTTP setReadTimeOut can work if Network Not Available after posting data to server and waiting for responce from server

Tags: android, communication

I was Posting Data from Android Mobile to Server over HTTP connection. I was able to POST data to server and also get acknowledgement from Server. But sometime if my server communication thread waiting for acknowledgement from server after posting data that time i loss Internet Connectivity and thread unable to receive Ack from server and goes in infinite loop. I tried setReadTimeOut(180000) method.

Can it work for me? Can it gives SocketTimeOutException if no network Available/ No connection between server and mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a timeout will most likely work. However, I would not recommend setting it to 180000 (= 180 seconds = 3 minutes!). 30 seconds is usually more than enough. You also might want to add a [setConnectTimeout](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))

Note that there are some situations where an HttpUrlConnection doesn't always work properly:

1. Android versions 2.2 or earlier, better use the Apache HTTP client for these versions (see also [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html))
2. On the emulator (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522632/741249))